# heuristics - is N a prime number?

Tags: algorithm, primes, heuristics

I read a positive integer N from the stdin and I'm trying to figure out if N is a prime number.

I know I can divide N to all the positive numbers up to sqrt(N), but that's time consuming and my algorithm affords to give false positives from time to time so I'm looking for an heuristic to solve this.

I remember I learned about an algorithm in collage last year that would pick a number, then check if N is divisible by that number (or it's factors) and if not, then it could tell N is a prime, but it would falsely identify it as prime about 1/40 of the time.

Does anyone recognize this algorithm I'm talking about?
A link to it would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to be so fast? What are you optimizing for?

Comment: @Diego Basch: I'm optimizing for a job interview :)

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay-Strassen_primality_test - by the way, that's a terrible interview question. Did someone actually ask it, or do you think it may come up?

Comment: @DiegoBasch: Optimizing this issue is very important when dealing with big numbers, which is something that is not as uncommon as you might think. something that runs in `O(log(n)^k)` is much better then `O(sqrt(n))` for large numbers. It also raises an interesting issue in theory, since `O(sqrt(n))` is exponential in the input (the length of the bit representation of `n`), while logarithmic answers aren't.

Comment: @Amit, that is a complete nonsequitur. You have no idea what my background is. I asked the OP what *he* is trying to optimize for.

Comment: @DiegoBasch: Sorry if it seemed like a personal offense or something - the comment is actually more for anyone who might read it, not specifically to you, trying to explain why logarithmic algorithms to the primality test is important, sorry if I offended you in some way.

Comment: @DiegoBasch: Haven't been to the interview yet but I'm sure this is going to come up.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are a few probabilistic algorithsm, some described in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_testing_versus_primality_proving), most likely you are speaking about <strike>[Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)</strike> [Fermat Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)

Note that since 2002 there is actually a O(log(n)^6) deterministic approach to determine if a number is prime - called [AKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) (after its developers)<sup>1</sup>

---

It is an interesting issue - many thought that primality test cannot be done both polynomially in the size of the input (i.e. logarithmic in `n`) and both deterministically, but their approach showed otherwise.

Comment: Actually I was talking about the Fermat primality test that I found with your help. I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Fermat primality test is not reliable - there are many composite numbers where it isn't better than trial division, but much slower. Miller-Rabin is just slightly more complicated than Fermat, usually at least twice as fast, and _reliable_.